# Is WillEnterForeground not working properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

My iOS app has a requirement that if you suspend the app for a certain amount of time (say one hour) we want the app to return **not** to where you was before, but **to the home screen**.  The idea is that you drill down into the app, look something up, and then forget about it.  An hour later when you need the app again, what you were doing before is irrelevant and we just want to auto-start again at the home screen.

I have implemented this with `DidEnterBackground` and `WillEnterForeground` and it works almost perfectly.  When the app goes to background, I write a timestamp.  When it resumes, I compare the timestamp with the current time, and if greater than the 1 hour window, I pop everything off the ViewController stack, with animation=false, and we are home.

This works on iPad and in all simulators, but on my iPhone, it shows the previous screen for a fraction of a second before going home, **even though** `WillEnterForeground` comes before it should be visible, and it's popped off the stack without animation, and so shouldn't be visible.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because iOS deliberately takes a snapshot of the window before backgrounding your app, then displays it when resuming, to give the impression of a snappier interface. From Apple's docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html):

> When an app transitions to the background, the system takes a snapshot
>   of the app’s main window, which it then presents briefly when
>   transitioning your app back to the foreground. Before returning from
>   your applicationDidEnterBackground: method, you should hide or obscure
>   passwords and other sensitive personal information that might be
>   captured as part of the snapshot.

So the answer is to remove or somehow blank the view in `applicationDidEnterBackground` (by, for instance, setting the root view's alpha to 0.0) so you can then decide on resume whether it should be displayed again.